# Netflix Zuul-AWS Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, netflix-zuul

I am trying to implement Netflix Zuul for load balancing traffic between different ELB's in different regions. Can somebody suggest good tutorial or any alternative method for load balancing ELB traffic.